# "System cannot find the path specified" error for GDAL_DRIVER_PATH in Anaconda prompt

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal

I have installed GDAL/OGR for Python using Anaconda, but now whenever I launch the Anaconda prompt, I get the error "Het systeem kan het opgegeven pad niet vinden.", which is Dutch for "System cannot find the path specified". This is followed by

```
set "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH="
```

How could I solve this?

It's not causing any problems in particular, but it seems like this is not intended behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem. It should be solved by uninstalling gdal.
Just Use:

```
conda uninstall gdal
```

This worked for me. It is probably a problem with package.

Comment: Watch ...
Your answer, in addition to being considered a comment. It is poorly done. This platform is not just any forum. We are the largest help and support center for other programmers and developers in the world. Review the terms of the community.