# "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=" error when installing geopandas

Tags: python, anaconda, gdal, geopandas

I am trying to install geopandas using anaconda prompt but I keep getting this error with `gdal`:

```
O sistema não conseguiu localizar o caminho especificado.

C:\Users\John Smith>set "GDAL_DRIVER_PATH="
```

Another user seems to have had the exact same problem:

["System cannot find the path specified" error for GDAL_DRIVER_PATH in Anaconda prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55952045/system-cannot-find-the-path-specified-error-for-gdal-driver-path-in-anaconda-p)

Uninstalling `gdal` doesn't solve the issue as geopandas seems to require its installation.

I have tried installing it in python version 3.7 a well, but the error is the same.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while installing geopandas. I solved it by installing gdal in Conda. It can be installed by using:

```
conda install gdal
```

Due to some reason, Anaconda 3.6 is not installing the gdal by default.
I hope that helps.